# DBpedia query giving me error when using jena

Tags: sparql, jena, dbpedia

When i run this query on dbpedia.org

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?resource ?label ?location 
WHERE 
  { 
    <http://dbpedia.org/resource/New_York_City> geo:geometry ?sourcegeo . 
    ?resource geo:geometry ?location ; 
                                 rdfs:label ?label . 
    FILTER( bif:st_intersects( ?location, ?sourcegeo, 20 ) ) . 
    FILTER( lang( ?label ) = "en" ) 
  }
```

it is producing results fine but same query gives me error when using java jena api.

```
 String s2 = "SELECT DISTINCT ?resource ?label ?location \r\n" + 
        "WHERE \r\n" + 
        "  { \r\n" + 
        "    <http://dbpedia.org/resource/New_York_City> geo:geometry ?sourcegeo . \r\n" + 
        "    ?resource geo:geometry ?location ; \r\n" + 
        "                                 rdfs:label ?label . \r\n" + 
        "    FILTER( bif:st_intersects( ?location, ?sourcegeo, 20 ) ) . \r\n" + 
        "    FILTER( lang( ?label ) = \"en\" ) \r\n" + 
        "  }\r\n" + 
        "";

    Query query = QueryFactory.create(s2); //s2 = the query above
    QueryExecution qExe = QueryExecutionFactory.sparqlService( "http://dbpedia.org/sparql", query );
    ResultSet results = qExe.execSelect();
    ResultSetFormatter.out(System.out, results, query) ;
```

it gives me the following errors

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.jena.query.QueryParseException: Line 4, column 49: Unresolved prefixed name: geo:geometry
    at org.apache.jena.sparql.lang.ParserBase.throwParseException(ParserBase.java:521)
    at org.apache.jena.sparql.lang.ParserBase.resolvePName(ParserBase.java:286)
    at org.apache.jena.sparql.lang.sparql_11.SPARQLParser11.PrefixedName(SPARQLParser11.java:4857)
    at org.apache.jena.sparql.lang.sparql_11.SPARQLParser11.iri(SPARQLParser11.java:4841) and it goes on
```

Comment: `Unresolved prefixed name: geo:geometry` -> I'm just wondering, isn't this error message clear enough?

Answer (score 2):

DBPedia has a number of [Predefined Namespace Prefixes](http://sv.dbpedia.org/sparql?nsdecl), which includes

`PREFIX geo: <http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#>`,

which Jena does not have. Hence you have to specify it for use Jena before your `SELECT`. I.e.

```
String s2 = "PREFIX geo: <http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#>\r\n" +
            "SELECT DISTINCT ?resource ?label ?location \r\n" + 
            ... etc
```

Comment: While you can add most of the prefixes, `bif` is the prefix for Virtuoso built in functions and is specific to endpoints using Virtuoso

Comment: Thank you for your answers.
@chrisis but Dbpedia is using Virtuoso so bif prefix should not be a problem, right? After adding all prefixes in java jena I keep getting this error "Exception in thread "main" HttpException: 400 HTTP 400 error making the query: Bad Request"

Comment: @chrisis for `bif`, you can use `<bif:st_intersects>` - it will be handled correctly by Virtuoso.

Comment: @firebone What did you use for `bif` as namespace? You can use  `<bif:st_intersects>` - it will be handled correctly by Virtuoso and also parsed properly by Jena. 400 means illegal query syntax for sure, please show the modified query and don't forget to use line breaks etc. - you can check the "real" query with `System.out.println()`

Comment: @AKSW I tried to use <bif:st_intersects> as namespace but it still gives me 400 error. I changed a query little bit so it looks like this now
`PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX geo: <http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#>
PREFIX dbr: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
PREFIX bif: <bif:st_intersects>
SELECT ?placeName WHERE
{
  dbr:New_York_City geo:geometry ?ny .
  ?place geo:geometry ?placeGeometry .
  ?place rdfs:label ?placeName .

  FILTER(bif:st_distance(?ny, ?placeGeometry) < 10)
  FILTER (LANG(?placeName) = 'en')
}`

Comment: **not** as namespace...simply use `<bif:st_intersects>` inside the query and remove the prefix declaration of , anything else wouldn't make sense or not? by the way, you should carefully read the error messages that you get and try to understand them. currently, you're getting `Virtuoso 37000 Error SP030: SPARQL compiler, line 6: Prefixes 'sql:' and 'bif:' are reserved for SQL names at '<bif:st_intersects>' before 'SELECT'` - isn't this clear enough?